# How to prove semantical equivalence?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Prove that:

> If $ \alpha \equiv \beta $ and $ \beta \equiv \gamma $ then $ \alpha \equiv \gamma $

I know that:

$ \alpha \equiv \beta $ if and only if $ \alpha \leftrightarrow \beta $ is a tautology.

Should I use this theorem to prove the semantic equivalence, or should I go another way?

Comment: I would go another way, by just using the definitions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation

Comment: Can you define ≡?  Does (A ≡ B) mean the same as [(A |= B) and (B |= A)]?

Answer (score 1):

Take any formulae $α,β,γ$ such that $α \equiv β \equiv γ$.

Given any interpretation of atomic propositions:

If $α$ is true, what can you say about $β$?

If $β$ is true, what can you say about $γ$?

Similarly in the reverse direction.

Therefore can you conclude that $α \equiv γ$?

Answer (score 0):

Using Polish notation, can you manage to show from your premises that C$\alpha$$\gamma$ and C$\gamma$$\alpha$ are both tautologies?